# How to monitor a socket

Tags: c, sockets

I try to write a chat app using C sockets 
    After I open a socket, I would like to monitor the socket to see if it ready to read or     write and call a function when receive data .

Answer (score 2):

You need an I/O Multiplexer: it will trigger when certain conditions you set are satisfied such as reading, writing, error and so on.
Depending on the OS you are targetting, you may go for `select`, `poll`, `kqueue`, `epoll` although for small amounts of sockets `select` is arguably the best one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `select()` system call.
For detail you can reference [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)